# Python TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
def parallelUpdateJSON(submatrix):
    with open('geo.geojson') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for feature in data: 
        currentfeature = submatrix[(submatrix['SId']==feature['properties']['cellId'])]
        if (len(currentfeature) > 0):
            feature['properties'].update({"style": {"opacity": currentfeature.AllActivity.item()}})
        else:
            feature['properties'].update({"style": {"opacity": 0}})


pool = Pool()
pool.map(parallelUpdateJSON, submatrix)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Here, `submatrix` is a `pandas` dataframe:

```
submatrix.dtypes

Index          1200240
SId            1200240
Weekday        1200240
Hour           1200240
Internet       1200240
SmsIn          1200240
SmsOut         1200240
CallIn         1200240
CallOut        1200240
AllActivity    1200240
dtype: int64
```

I get the error that somewhere I'm using strings as indices instead of integers, but I can't seem to figure out, where. The error is `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Could you help me find what I'm doing wrong?

Full stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-19-3d3715e97af2>", line 5, in parallelUpdateJSON
    currentfeature = submatrix[(submatrix['SId']==feature['properties']['cellId'])]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-d6121ed2750b> in <module>()
----> 1 writeGeoJSON(6, 15, baseline)

<ipython-input-19-3d3715e97af2> in writeGeoJSON(weekdaytopredict, hourtopredict, predictionmatrix)
     16     #func = partial(parallelUpdateJSON, data)
     17     pool = Pool()
---> 18     pool.map(parallelUpdateJSON, submatrix)
     19     pool.close()
     20     pool.join()

/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    258         in a list that is returned.
    259         '''
--> 260         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    261 
    262     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    606             return self._value
    607         else:
--> 608             raise self._value
    609 
    610     def _set(self, i, obj):

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: The stack trace *flat-out tells you* where it's happening -- on this line: `currentfeature = submatrix[(submatrix['SId']==feature['properties']['cellId'])]`. It seems that either `feature` or `feature['properties']` is evaluating as a string, not a dict.

Comment: The error message tells you that for a string you can only use integer indices. In the line causing the error there are no indices that could be integers (all the indices are string literals), so the problem is probably that one of the objects that gets indexed is a string instead of a map.

Comment: when you use map, do remember that the second argument doesn't actually get fed to `parallelUpdateJSON`. Only a certain item from it gets sent to `parallelUpdateJSON` and that item is probably a string.